# Searchview Activity changing Fragment Content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have been following this tutorial in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9_hcfWVkIc&t=1231s) that teaches how to filter recyclerview content.

But we have different implementation.

My desired Application has an **activity that has a searchview that searches a fragment recyclerview** while his only has one activity.

This is my code:
**HomeActivity**

```
 FragmentSearch fs;   
fs = new FragmentSearch();
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
   return fs.filterHandler(newText);
}
```

**FragmentSearch**

```
 public boolean filterHandler(String newText){
    newText = newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<Product> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Product product: productArrayList){
        String name = product.getName().toLowerCase();
        if(name.contains(newText)){
            newList.add(product);
        }
    }
    adapter.setFilter(newList);
    return true;
}
```

The difference would be in the OnQueryTextSubmit, I tried to create a method in the fragment that will accept the users query

The Error:

> 07-12 13:54:52.038 6262-6262/com.example.earlcscabanig.thestoreapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   07-12 13:54:56.948 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:56.948 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:56.958 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:56.978 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:56.978 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:56.988 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:57.008 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:57.018 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:57.018 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:57.038 1086-1479/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
>   07-12 13:54:57.058 6262-6262/com.example.earlcscabanig.thestoreapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.earlcscabanig.thestoreapp, PID: 6262
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.example.earlcscabanig.thestoreapp.fragments.FragmentSearch.filterHandler(FragmentSearch.java:82)
>           at com.example.earlcscabanig.thestoreapp.HomeActivity.onQueryTextChange(HomeActivity.java:144)

There was a **NullPointer** as well **as Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering**

Answer (score 0):

User [Filterable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable) with `RecyclerView Adapter`. This is best way to filter data with RecyclerView. Below are some demo examples,

1. https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo
2. https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/